# Where does Windows search for device drivers?

Tags: windows, drivers

I'm working on a utility for a USB connected device.  The vendor has given me the device drivers, but I have to install them manually.

When I finish my utility, I'd like to be able to have the setup put the drivers in the right location so that Windows can auto install them.  where do I need to put the driver files in order for windows to be able to find them automatically when the device is connected?

Along the same lines, is there a process for submitting drivers to Microsoft so that Windows can download them automatically instead of having to include them with my utility?

I'm working with W7, but will also need to support Vista and XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You submit your hardware to Microsoft via the Windows Logo program.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463054

.

Drivers are submitted via the WHQL logo testing program

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487521#ETD

The inf file for the driver will be located in the C:\Windows\inf folder, the driver itself is in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers folder (someone correct me if this is wrong)